# Laravel Eloquent get every nth of relation

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am querying a relation from a model, but since I want to limit the amount of rows that the relation returns to a set number (in this example 18), I've mapped the relation.

```
$sensors = Sensor::where('building_id', $request->building_id)->with('data_sensor')->get()->map(function($sensor) {
      $sensor->setRelation('data_sensor', $sensor->data_sensor->sortByDesc('created_at')->take(18)->values());
      return $sensor;
});
```

This works fine. However I am trying to get every nth row of my relation, in this example I want every 6th row.

I've tried the following (added whereRaw), but this gave an error that the whereRaw method doesn't exist.

```
$sensors = Sensor::where('building_id', $request->building_id)->with('data_sensor')->get()->map(function($sensor) {
      $sensor->setRelation('data_sensor', $sensor->data_sensor->sortByDesc('created_at')->whereRaw( DB::raw('(`id`) % 6 != 0') )->take(18)->values());
      return $sensor;
});
```

How can I get every nth of my relation, with a limit so it doesn't return all rows of the relation?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use a querybuilder method in a collection, that's the reason for the error.

Try this:

```
        $sensors = Sensor::where('building_id', $request->building_id)
        ->with('data_sensor')
        ->get()
        ->map(function($sensor) {
            $sensor->setRelation(
                'data_sensor', 
                $sensor->data_sensor->sortByDesc('created_at')->filter(function($s) { return $s->id % 6 != 0; })->take(18)->values());
            return $sensor;
        });
```